# Running and retrieving process on remote linux machine using java code

Tags: java, linux, runtime

I am running a process on a remote linux machine through java. I need to retrieve each line of processing in a string in my java code during runtime. How do I achieve this?

I am currently using sshxcute-1.0 jar inorder to connect to my remote machine and run my commands. It has a method Result.sysout which returns the entire console of the processing on my remote machine as a string. But this happens only after the entire process concludes.

I would like to retrieve each and every line of processing as it happens during runtime without closing my connection with the remote machine. Is it possible?

Comment: can't you use PuTTY? Also I don't think retrieving each line of output while program executes on remote is appropriate.

Comment: Well, I actually need to process further, the data from few of the lines, independently using my java code.